# How to call a method in the bean when a JSF page is requested?

Tags: jsp, jsf

How to call a method in the bean when a JSF page is requested?
Example I have a JSF page "MyPage.jsf" and its backend bean "MyBean" and it has a method "myMethod()".
Is it possible to call the MyBean.myMethod() when MyPage.jsf is requested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have added MyBean in the faces-config.xml as a managed bean:

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>myBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>MyBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

When you use the Bean in your MyPage.jsf example:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.mytext}"/>
```

The default constructor of MyBean will automatically be called. Execute myMethod() from the default constructor.

```
public MyBean() {
  this.myMethod();
}
```

And it will get called on page load.