# jsf navigation to another method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am developing an application using jsf 2.0 and i have the following situation:
I have 2 managed beans.
On the first managed bean i have a method that process some data and then store the result in session.After the data was stored in session i need to invoke a method on the second bean that will display the information from session.
The problem is that if i return a string from the first bean method that correspond to the seconds bean method view the data is not processed, and of course not displayed.

What i need is some navigation rule that from the first bean would redirect me to the second bean method, and the second bean method would return a string with the corresponding view name.

- update

maybe a

```
<f:event listener="#{secondBean.methodToBeInvoked}" type="preRenderView" />
```

would help me achieve that.
Is this the right approach ?

Comment: That's not how JSF navigation flow works. In JSF, you return Strings as your action method outcomes when you want to navigate to another view. Then, that view is loaded and the bean which view refers is called. However, can you post your code?

Comment: What's your managed beans scope (request, view)?

Comment: My both beans are request scoped. I also have a session scope bean to carry the date between them.

Comment: Can you post the managed bean codes ?

Comment: i guess that this was what i needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988784/how-to-call-a-method-in-the-bean-when-a-jsf-page-is-requested